# Display parent information for inner_hits response

Tags: elasticsearch

*Apologies, the configs make this question quite long*

I have a schema that looks something like this:

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "mytype": {
            "properties": {
                "event_datetime": {"type": "date"},
                "elements": {
                    "type": "nested",
                    "properties": {
                        "name": {"type": "keyword"},
                        "id": {"type": "text"},
                        "type": {"type": "keyword"},
                        "content": {
                            "type": "nested",
                            "properties": {
                                "html": {"type": "text"},
                                "label": {"type": "keyword"},
                                "text": {"type": "text"},
                                "title": {"type": "text"}
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to find entries where the `elements.content.html` contains, say `http`:

```
{
    "_source": ["event_datetime"],
    "query": {
        "nested": {
            "path": "elements.content",
            "query": {
                "wildcard": {"elements.content.html": "*http*"}
            },
            "inner_hits": {}
        }
    }
}
```

This is what the relevant part of the response looks like

```
"_source": {
    "event_datetime": "2019-01-22T05:24:21"
},
"inner_hits": {
    "elements.content": {
        "hits": {
            "total": 1,
            "max_score": 1,
            "hits": [{
                "_index": "my_index",
                "_type": "mytype",
                "_id": "ABC",
                "_nested": {
                    "field": "elements",
                    "offset": 73,
                    "_nested": {
                        "field": "content",
                        "offset": 0
                    }
                },
                "_score": 1,
                "_source": {
                    "html": "blah https blah"
                }
    }...}
```

*What I would like*

I would like to `elements.type` to be included in the response.

I've tried various permutations of adding `"_source" : ["elements.content.html", "elements.type"]` into various levels but haven't figured out how to get the `elements.type` information attached to the response object (*somewhere*, don't really care where, as long as its attached and easily navigable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this you need `inner_hits` at parent level i.e. at `elements` level. You can therefore rephrase you query as below which is nested query inside nested query.

```
{
  "_source": [
    "event_datetime"
  ],
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "elements",
      "inner_hits": {
        "_source": [
          "elements.type",
          "elements.content.html"
        ]
      },
      "query": {
        "nested": {
          "path": "elements.content",
          "query": {
            "wildcard": {
              "elements.content.html": "*http*"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```